# Sort through list of nodes which have two dimensional properties

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, binary-tree, nodes

This is my Node class

```
public class Node
{
    int Data= -1;
    int X;
    int Y;
    Node LeftChild = null;
    Node RightChild = null;
    Node(int i)
    {
        this.Data = i;
    }
}
```

This is my Inorder traversal code:

```
public static void inorder(Node current, int horiz_dist, int verti_dist)
{
    if(current == null)
        return;
    inorder(current.LeftChild, ++horiz_dist, ++verti_dist);
    horiz_dist--;
    verti_dist--;
    System.out.println("Node "+current.Data+": X = "+horiz_dist+", Y = "+verti_dist);
    current.X = horiz_dist;
    current.Y = verti_dist;
    node_list.add(current);
    inorder(current.RightChild, --horiz_dist, ++verti_dist);
    horiz_dist++;
    verti_dist--;
}
```

I have a list of nodes which I got from iterating a binary tree in Inorder traversal. Following is output from that traversal:

> Node 18: X = 3, Y = 3
>
> Node 7: X = 2, Y = 2
>
> Node 5: X = 1, Y = 1
>
> Node 12: X = 1, Y = 3
>
> Node 9: X = 0, Y = 2
>
> Node 13: X = -1, Y = 3
>
> Node 6: X = 0, Y = 0
>
> Node 8: X = -1, Y = 1
>
> Node 10: X = -2, Y = 2
>
> Node 15: X = -3, Y = 3

I want to sort All nodes based on `X` first (Decreasing order) and then `Y` (Increasing order). Where `X` and `Y` are the distance from the Root Node respectively. So final output will be:

> Node 18: X = 3, Y = 3
>
> Node 7: X = 2, Y = 2
>
> Node 5: X = 1, Y = 1
>
> Node 12: X = 1, Y = 3
>
> Node 6: X = 0, Y = 0
>
> Node 9: X = 0, Y = 2
>
> Node 8: X = -1, Y = 1
>
> Node 13: X = -1, Y = 3
>
> Node 10: X = -2, Y = 2
>
> Node 15: X = -3, Y = 3

EDIT: This is my comparator logic. I updated it. Now it worked

```
This is comparator logic I wrote:
```

`Collections.sort(node_list, new Comparator(){

```
        public int compare(Node second, Node first)

        {

            if(first.X > second.X)
                return 1;
            else if(first.X < second.X)
                return -1;
            else if(first.X == second.X)
            {
                if(first.Y < second.Y)
                    return 1;
                else if(first.Y > second.Y)
                    return -1;
                else if( first.Y == second.Y)
                    return 0;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });`
```

Comment: I retracted my answer when I realized I misunderstood the question. Sorry about that! But you can use ArrayList::sort since I think you're using Java with a custom comparator. That's your easiest solution. However, if it's like a homework solution since you're rolling your own BST here, what you need for this kind of traversal is a queue. You can't do it recursively using your standard pre-order/inorder/post-order traversal since we need to traverse the tree one "row" at a time. These recursive algorithms always dig their way down to the leaves instead of processing in "rows".

Comment: So if you want to do it without relying on a separate sorting algorithm, you have to process your tree on row at a time, from left-to-right (or right-to-left for descending X order), top-to-bottom. To do that, you need to pass over each row of the tree in "phases" from right to left, pushing to the queue. Or easier if you use two queues, one for the "current row" and another for the "next row". Then swap the queues when the current one becomes empty and repeat until both are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::sort with custom comparison function.

Let say you have a vector of Nodes `std::vector<Node> vec` then, You can use it like this

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare);
```

where `compare` is defined as below

```
bool compare(Node a, Node b)
{
    if (a.X > a.X) return true;
    if (a.Y > a.Y) return true;
}
```

running time for this algorithm is `O(n*log(n))`

Comment: Can you show example for std::sort? I am not familiar with method. How much time it will take. Normally for two dimensional comparisons it will go in O(N^2) time. I wanted to know if it can be done in O(N*logN) time.

Answer (score 0):

Phew, let's try this again since I misunderstood the question originally. Since your whole goal is to assign these X/Y values through the process of tree traversal, first the bad news:

*Recursive algorithms don't work here.*

Whether you're using in-order or pre-order or post-order traversal, all of these algorithms fall apart since they want to dig their way down to the leaves recursively in a stack-like LIFO fashion (recursion uses the call stack like a LIFO structure). They would be fine if you wanted to output in a way sorted Y first then X, but not the other way around. To do X first is considerably trickier.

Pseudocode solution:

```
List<Node> current_row;
List<Node> next_row;

root_node.x = 0;
root_node.y = 0;
current_row.push(root_node);

// Right-to-Left, Top-to-Bottom
while (!current_row.empty())
{
    do
    {
        Node node = current_row.pop();
        // output node data

        if (node.right_child)
        {
            node.right_child.x = node.x + 1;
            node.right_child.y = node.y + 1;
            next_row.push(node.right_child);
        }

        if (node.left_child)
        {
            node.left_child.x = node.x - 1;
            node.left_child.y = node.y + 1;
            next_row.push(node.left_child);
        }
    } while (!current_row.empty());
    current_row.swap(next_row);
}
```

You can also use a single queue here but I thought this 'row-based' mentality might help you a bit more initially to understand what's going on.